# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable in scikit learn predict

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am storing a pickle of a xgboost classifier model file to disk using joblib

```python
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(clf, 'model.pkl')
```

Then, I am loading the model and trying to predict on a test dataset

```python
from sklearn.externals import joblib
model=joblib.load('model.pkl')
model.predict(X_test)
```

I am getting the `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` when I execute the predict method on the loaded classifier object.

Any help on how to resolve this?

Here is the traceback

```python
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-0da70f003ba0> in <module>()
----> 1 model.predict(X_test)

C:\Users\Sriram\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py in <lambda>(*args, **kwargs)
    113 
    114         # lambda, but not partial, allows help() to work with update_wrapper
--> 115         out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    116         # update the docstring of the returned function
    117         update_wrapper(out, self.fn)

C:\Users\Sriram\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in predict(self, X)
    314             if transform is not None:
    315                 Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
--> 316         return self.steps[-1][-1].predict(Xt)
    317 
    318     @if_delegate_has_method(delegate='_final_estimator')

C:\Users\Sriram\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py in predict(self, data, output_margin, ntree_limit)
    461     def predict(self, data, output_margin=False, ntree_limit=0):
    462         test_dmatrix = DMatrix(data, missing=self.missing)
--> 463         class_probs = self.booster().predict(test_dmatrix,
    464                                              output_margin=output_margin,
    465                                              ntree_limit=ntree_limit)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: you are loading your model to an object called `model` but then you are  using `model_xgboost`

Comment: Please post the full traceback

Comment: @MaximilianPeters updated it! I was using just `model` in my code btw!

Comment: @roganjosh posted the traceback

Comment: How are you training and storing the classifier in the first place? Please add the full code.

Comment: Thanks ppl! Found my problem! I was creating the model in a newer version of xgboost and using it in an older version of xgboost. Updating to the newer version rectified the error!